# How to specify OkHttp Client call correctly?

Tags: java, jetty, okhttp, jetty-9

I setup a Jetty Server (v9.3.0.M0) with a simple Jetty Servlet that writes the HttpServletRequest-body into the HttpServletResponse as follows:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SimpleServlet  extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        String testString = stringBuilder.toString();
        response.getWriter().println(testString);
   }

}
```

When I specify and run a JettyCient (v9.3.0.M0) much like this:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.ContentResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.BytesContentProvider;

public class JettyClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.start();

        ContentResponse response = client.POST("http://localhost:8083/hello")
                .content(new BytesContentProvider("this is a test".getBytes()), "text/plain")
                .send();

        System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());

        client.stop();
    }
}
```

it runs perfectly, i.e. the server responds as intended and it just writes out "this is a test".

When I specify an OkHttpClient (v2.0.0) much like this:

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.*;
import java.io.IOException;


public class OkHttpClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient client = new com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8"), "this is a test");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://localhost:8083/hello")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        System.out.println(response.body().toString());

    }
}
```

I end up with an empty body. Thus it seems like the body does not arrive at the server. 
Do I miss something important here?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Response.body().string()`, not `Response.body().to string()`.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse, but it still does not work, i.e. I get again an empty body.

Comment: Recently I have faced this problem as well. But for me if the post response status code is 200 then I am able to receive the response body message. But is the response status code is other than 200 (like 404,500 etc) I am not able to receive body message. @StefanSchröder did you able to figure out the problem? Thanks in advance